# Задача на использование структур

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Цель нижеприведенной задачи такова: запускаешь программу, вылазит строка

> Введите информацию о студентах, фамилию (буквами), факультет (цифрами), год рождения (цифрами)

Вводишь трех студентов и потом выскакивает еще одна строка

> Введите искомого студента

Вводишь фамилию любого из ранее введенных студентов и программа выдает все об этом студенте (факультет, год рождения). Так вот, нужно, чтоб факультет вводился не цифрами, а буквами, как фамилия. То есть чтоб прога выглядела не вот так

> Фамилия: Боготков Факультет: 23 Год рождения: 1994

а вот так

> Фамилия: Боготков Факультет: Информационная безопасность Год рождения: 1994

Я перепробовал множество вариантов, прога либо вообще не запускается, либо вырубается после первого нажатия Enter. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

```
#include <string.h>
#pragma hgrstop
#pragma argsused
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#define n 3
int main()
{
int i,k;
float sum;
struct tov
  {
   char name[10];
   float c;
   int kol;
  }t;
/*struct*/ tov mag[3];
char nazv[10];
clrscr();
printf("\n vvedite informaciyu stydentov\n");
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   printf("\n familia, fuckyltet, god rojdeniya: ");
   scanf("%s%f%d",&t.name,&t.c,&t.kol);
   mag[i]=t;
   getch();
  }
printf("\n Vvedite iskomogo stydenta: ");
scanf("%s",nazv);
for(i=0,sum=0,k=0;i<n;i++)
if(strcmp(mag[i].name,nazv)==0)
   {
    sum=mag[i].kol;
    getch();
    k=mag[i].c;
   }
printf("Familia: %s\t Fackyltet: %d\t God rojdeniya:%5.0f",nazv,k,sum);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Никитос, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме. Работа за автора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

беглым взгядом в глаза бросилось такие вещи: помоему структура объявляется ВНЕ main(), во вторых функция задержки пишеться _getch(); черточка впереди нужна кароче

еще у тебя поле name массив (name[10]) а в коде ты пытаешься занести данные как в обычную переменную (t.name) вроде нужен индекс

я уверен что у тебя кроме этого еще куча косяков, но под рукой нет компилятора, а на память плохо помню

Comment: прога отлично работает, ошибок в ней нет, просто нужно её переделать (как выше было сказано), я вот не знаю как.